# Poisson process and conditional probability.

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

> Airport travellers arive by a Poisson proces with rate $1000$ per hour. Of those travellers, $10\%$ is superficially inspected and an additional $1\%$ is extremely careful inspected. That is $11\%$ is inspected. Given that in $10$ minutes $15$ people have been superficially inspected, what is the probability that exactly $4$ people are extremely careful inspected?

If conditioning on the number of people (say $N$) arriving and summing over all possible values and the probability of $N$ people arriving, I can come up with: $\mathbb{P}(4\ $ people thoroughly inspected$)=\sum_x\mathbb{P}(4\ $ people thoroughly inspected$ \mid x\ $people arrive in $10$ minutes$)\mathbb{P}(x\ $people arrive in $10$ minutes$)=$ $$\sum_{x\geq 4} \binom {x}{4} \frac{1}{100}^4 \frac{99}{100}^{x-4} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1000}{6}} \frac{\frac{1000}{6}^{x}}{x!}$$ But then I do not use the given information, could someone help?

Comment: From the wordings, I guess the question is related to the decomposition of Poisson process. It is well known that the two streams (superficially and extremely careful) are independent Poisson processes. So in the calculation it does not account for the given information in the other process. Also technically speaking you should start with $\mathbb{P}\{N_C(\frac {1} {6}) = 4|N_S(\frac {1} {6}) = 15\}$, and by independence / or some calculation, the conditional part should cancel out eventually.

Comment: @BGM could you give a headstart? Having a little difficulty forming the equation.